# Getting value of specific field in complicated json file using fetch and map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

It seems a duplicated issue but really I can't find a solution.

I have an issue that I can't get specific values in a complex json file like this :

```
{
"get": "fixtures",
"parameters": {
    "date": "2024-01-17"
},
"errors": [],
"results": 218,
"paging": {
    "current": 1,
    "total": 1
},
"response": [
    {
        "fixture": {
            "id": 1156472,
            "referee": null,
            "timezone": "UTC",
            "date": "2024-01-17T00:00:00+00:00",
            "timestamp": 1705449600,
            "periods": {
                "first": null,
                "second": null
            },
            "venue": {
                "id": null,
                "name": "TBC",
                "city": "TBC"
            },
            "status": {
                "long": "Time to be defined",
                "short": "TBD",
                "elapsed": null
            }
        },
        "league": {
            "id": 667,
            "name": "Friendlies Clubs",
            "country": "World",
            "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/leagues/667.png",
            "flag": null,
            "season": 2024,
            "round": "Club Friendlies 3"
        },
        "teams": {
            "home": {
                "id": 675,
                "name": "Vasas",
                "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/675.png",
                "winner": null
            },
            "away": {
                "id": 646,
                "name": "Levski Sofia",
                "logo": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/646.png",
                "winner": null
            }
        },
        "goals": {
            "home": null,
            "away": null
        },
        "score": {
            "halftime": {
                "home": null,
                "away": null
            },
            "fulltime": {
                "home": null,
                "away": null
            },
            "extratime": {
                "home": null,
                "away": null
            },
            "penalty": {
                "home": null,
                "away": null
            }
        }
     },
     {
```

to fetch data I do like this :

```
let url = "http://localhost:8000/home/";

const [matches, setMatches] = useState([{}]);

const matchData = async () => {
  const res = await fetch(url);
    const d = await res.json();
  
    return setMatches(d.response);
}

useEffect(() => {
    matchData();
}, [{}]);
```

but when I want to test the returned values then I can't,I tried a lot of solutions.

```
 matches?.map((match, index) => (

                                console.log(match.teams.home)
                            ))
```

then I get this error :

`Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'home')`

and the same thing with other sub-levels like `date`, any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are initializing `matches` with `[{}]` in this line
`const [matches, setMatches] = useState([{}]);`

So, when your component renders for the first time, value of `match` is `{}` and so `match.teams` is `undefined` and hence the error. `useEffect` will only get triggered after an initial render. You have the following options here

1. Not initialize matches with `[{}]`, but with `[]`
2. Use `?.` operator (`match?.teams?.home`)
3. Check if match has any keys, using `Object.keys(match).length`

On a separate note, using `[{}]` as the second argument of `useEffect` is a bad idea. If you intended to run it only once, then replace the it with `[]`

Comment: `match?.teams?.home` is a solution but there are not better solution?

Comment: Depends on what you want to achieve here. You have these options
1. Use `?.` as suggestd
2. Not initialize `matches` with `[{}]`, but with `[]` 
3. Check if `match` has any keys, using `Object.keys(match).length` 
etc..

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that error because the initial value for your `matches` was `[{}]`. I believe you intended to initialize it as an empty array.
`[{}]` is not an empty array.
Instead, initialize it as `[]`.
<s>`const [matches, setMatches] = useState([{}]);`</s>
`const [matches, setMatches] = useState([]);`
The error is caused by the fact that the program attempts to map through your matches since it is not an empty array and when it accesses the object in the first index `{}`, it isn't able to locate the `teams` and `home` properties.

Also, don't use `{}` as a dependency for your `useEffect`
This would cause a rerender each time because the object reference changes after each render.
Just leave it empty as `[]` if you want to run it just once

The problem with your code in both cases is that you are trying to use `[{}]` as an empty array, which it is not.